# iMacros Frame Name Trouble Shooting

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, firebug, imacros

I am having a issue with my frame names constantly changing I have tried FRAME NAME=* and various other ways. I Think its not working because the webpage is set up as different html tabs.. I am not sure why but its not allowing me to extract any data from a separate hmtl tab that I open. I am thinking this is the issue but I cant figure it out.. Thanks

```
openAndExtract = "Code: ";
openAndExtract += "FRAME NAME="ext-comp-1494"" + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:There<SP>are<SP>no<SP>updates." + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "FRAME F=0" + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "TAG POS=3 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:01000978" + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "FRAME NAME="ext-comp-1489"" + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Search<SP>this<SP>feed<SP>|<SP>ShowAll<SP>Updates<SP>ShowAll*" + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "FRAME F=0" + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "TAG POS=3 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:01008153" + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "FRAME NAME="ext-comp-1484"" + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Search<SP>this<SP>feed<SP>|<SP>ShowAll<SP>Updates<SP>ShowAll*" + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "FRAME F=0" + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=EM ATTR=ID:ext-gen119" + NewLine;
openAndExtract += "FRAME NAME="ext-comp-1006"" + NewLine;
alert(iimGetLastExtract ());
PlayMacro = iimPlay(openAndExtract);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to dig in into HTML code. Compare the value you've recorded with iMacros and try to find in HTML code of the web page. In order to extract it from HTML code you will have to use some kind of regular expression or regex .

Then you have to use 2 macros . First to extract the HTML code, then JavaScript with extract the NAME value from HTML. And when you have it you will use it in second macro.

Example:

```
var macro1;

macro1 ="CODE:";
macro1 +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:some_class EXTRACT=HTM";

var macro2;

macro2 ="CODE:";
macro2 +='FRAME NAME="{{name}}"'+"\n";
macro2 +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:some_other_class "+"\n";

iimPlay(macro1)

var name=iimGetLastExtract();

name=name.match(/some_regular_expresion/);

iimSet("name",name)

iimPlay(macro2)
```

This would be the method. The rest is up to you. There is possibility that you will not find that name property since it can be hidden.